# Comparing 2 dataframes and setting a new column value based on whether data exists in first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that I would like to compare. If dataframe A has data from dataframe B, I would like to set the value in a column to `"Open"`, else set to `"New"`:

```
data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'B': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape'], 
         'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}

data2 = {'A': [1, 2, 6],'B': ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'], 'C': [10, 20, 60]}
```

In this case, this would be the result:

```
data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'B': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape'],
         'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
         'new_col': [Open, Open, New, New, New]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'B': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape'],
     'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

data2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1, 2, 6],
     'B': ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'],
     'C': [10, 20, 60]})

data1['new_col'] = np.where(data1.isin(data2).all(axis=1), 'Open', 'New')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indicator` parameter in left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), so is possible identify row from left side, working perfect if no duplicates by both columns in both DataFrames.

Then add new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

out = (df1.merge(df2, indicator='new_col', how='left')
         .assign(new_col = lambda x: x['new_col'].map({'both':'Open','left_only':'New'})))
print (out)
   A       B   C new_col
0  1   apple  10    Open
1  2  banana  20    Open
2  3  orange  30     New
3  4   apple  40     New
4  5   grape  50     New
```

General solution is create `MultiIndex`in both DataFrames and compare by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), new values set by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1).isin(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2))
out = df1.assign(new_col = np.where(mask, 'Open', 'New'))
print (out)
   A       B   C new_col
0  1   apple  10    Open
1  2  banana  20    Open
2  3  orange  30     New
3  4   apple  40     New
4  5   grape  50     New
```